# how do you calculate length, fragment flag and fragment offset?

Tags: ip, fragment, router

The IP datagram with size 3700 bytes, including the header 20 bytes, arrives at a router. The MTU of the router’s outgoing link is 1300 bytes. State the value of length, fragment flag and fragment offset of all fragments created by the router.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, or what your problem is, you may want to consider giving more information about what you're trying to achieve what programming language you're using using, anything to make it as easy as possible to answer your query

Answer (score 2):

Since the MTU is 1300 bytes, we can stuff in a maximum of 1300-20=1280 bytes of data per fragment. Our data is 3700-20 = 3680 Bytes. 
So two fragments of 1280, and one fragment of 1120 Bytes will do.

1st Fragment: Length = 1300 Bytes. More Fragment Flag is set. The fragment offset is 0.

2nd Fragment: Length = 1300 Bytes. More Fragment Flag is set. The fragment offset is 1280/8 = 160.

3rd Fragment: Length = 1140 Bytes (1120+20). More Fragment Flag is not set since it is the last fragment. The fragment offset is 320.